# \tkzDrawLine doesn't print node

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've made this drawing, but I can manage to place the node $m$ to the line. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (M) at (0,0) ;
\coordinate (A) at (canvas polar cs:angle=90,radius=3cm);
\coordinate (B) at (canvas polar cs:angle=20,radius=3cm) ;
\draw (M) circle (3cm);
\draw (A) -- (B) ;
\tkzDefMidPoint(A,B) \tkzGetPoint{P}
\draw (A) -- (P) node[midway,sloped] {$// $} ;
\draw (P) -- (B) node[midway,sloped] {$// $} ;
\tkzDrawLine[add = 0.5 and 1.6](P,M) node {m}; %PROBLEM%
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,M);
\tkzLabelPoints(B,M);
\tkzLabelPoints[above](A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `node {m};` text is not part of a TikZ path. You will place the node manually or use one of the `\tkz…` macros or options for that.

Comment: @macmadness86 ... It is marked in the code... %PROBLEM% ;-)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel thanks, I added the line
    \node at (2.5,3) {$m$};
but I thought there should be a better solution.

Comment: @Arne You can use `\tkzDrawLine[add = 0.5 and 1.6, start=m, start style={midway}](P,M)` (or `end` instead of `start`). Usually those two nodes default to `at start` (= `pos = 0`) and `at end` (= `pos = 1`) but you can overwrite this with the `… style` keys.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks. I've used the     \tkzDrawLine[add = 0.5 and 1.6, start=$m$](P,M) It solved my problem.
But how can I check that my question is answered, since this is a comment?

Comment: In general tkz commands do not have `;` in the end

Comment: @percusse Thanks, but sometimes when I don't put ; TeXPad can't finish the compilation. So to be sure, I always put a ;.

Comment: You can't accept comments, but I'm sure @Qrrbrbirlbel will write an answer as soon as he has time.

Comment: @percusse when I use the correct syntax's I can indeed skip the ;
I stopped using \coordinate and changed it to \tkzDefPoint this works better now without the ;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The macros of the `tkz-*` packages are all wrappers around TikZ paths. A simple `node {m};` is therefore not part of any path (like every `;` after any of the `\tkz*` macros).

The `\tkzDrawLine` macro provides the keys

- `start`,
- `end`,
- `start style` and
- `end style`

to add nodes to the path, the `* style` can be used to apply another `pos`ition besides `at start` and `at end`.

In this example, I have used `near start` to show the affect:

```
\tkzDrawLine[add = 0.5 and 1.6, start=$m$, start style={near start}](P,M)
```

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (M) at (0,0) ;
\coordinate (A) at (canvas polar cs:angle=90,radius=3cm);
\coordinate (B) at (canvas polar cs:angle=20,radius=3cm) ;
\draw (M) circle (3cm);
\draw (A) -- (B) ;
\tkzDefMidPoint(A,B) \tkzGetPoint{P}
\draw (A) -- (P) node[midway,sloped] {$// $} ;
\draw (P) -- (B) node[midway,sloped] {$// $} ;
\tkzDrawLine[add = 0.5 and 1.6, start=$m$, start style={near start}](P,M)
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,M);
\tkzLabelPoints(B,M);
\tkzLabelPoints[above](A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]